# Could you give me a list of the most authoritative and prestigious manuals for introduction to classic logic?

Tags: logic

Could you give me a list of the most authoritative and prestigious manuals or textbooks for introduction to classic logic currently used in higher education?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. I hope your stay is a pleasant one. Good thoughts, good words, good deeds. :) ^^ :D  

Comment: #Tautological Revelations Thank you! I participate in other Stack Exchanges.

Comment: Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an exhaustive list, by any means, but here goes:

- David Barker-Plummer, Jon Barwise, John Etchemendy: Language, Proof and Logic
- George Boolos, John Burgess, Richard Jeffrey: Computability and Logic
- Irving Copi, Carl Cohen, Victor Rodych: Introduction to Logic
- Herbert Enderton: A Mathematical Introduction to Logic
- Christopher Leary and Lars Kristiansen: A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic
- Elliot Mendelson: Introduction to Mathematical Logic
- Mark Sainsbury: Logical Forms
- Peter Smith: An Introduction to Formal Logic
- Lori Watson, Patrick Hurley: A Concise Introduction to Logic

Of these, some are aimed more at math students and others more at philosophy students, and perhaps some at both.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you also peruse Irving M. Copi's *Symbolic Logic*, which he is supposed to have written as a companion to the  *Introduction to Logic* mentioned by Bumble.  (see https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/287494.)